# Android BottomSheet bounce animation

Tags: android, android-animation, bottom-sheet

[image]

I want to bounce effect when doing STATE_EXPANDED or STATE_COLLAPSED like above image

I want an animation with BounceInterpolator applied.

The code below is an example I made.

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/main_button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="click me !!"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="BottomSheetTitle!!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val mainButton: MaterialButton by lazy { findViewById(R.id.main_button) }
val bottomSheet: ConstraintLayout by lazy { findViewById(R.id.main_bottom_sheet) }
val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout> by lazy { BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mainButton.setOnClickListener {
        when (bottomSheetBehavior.state) {
            (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) -> {
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
            (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) -> {
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

there is no bounce.

Is there any solution to apply bounce animation?

1----------------------------------1

I solved using below code

I don't think this solution good

Answer please anytime if you have better good solution

```
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
                bottomSheet.animate()
                    .translationY(0f)
            }
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                bottomSheet.animate()
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .translationY(20f)
            }
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                bottomSheet.animate()
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .translationY(-20f)
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        }
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This animation is called `overshoot`. This is my try using `setWindowsAnimation(res int style)`:

```
mainBottomSheet.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.SlideAnimation);
```

and in `styles.xml` add your favorite animations as follow:

```
<style name="SlideAnimation" parent="Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in</item>
      <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out</item>
</style>
```

Add the following files in `res/anime` directory:

```
<!-- slide_in.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="700"
     android:interpolator="@anim/interpolator_slight_overshoot">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>

</set>
```

and its important part that makes animation as you want, is the interpolator:

```
<!-- interpolator_slight_overshoot.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<overshootInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:tension="1.0"/>
```

**Disclaimer:** Source of animations: [Alerter library](https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter/tree/master)